# Cannot format React code properly in Sublime Text 3

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3, indentation

Seems like this should be straight forward but i cant seem to get the correct format for React code upon an indent key binding. It indents after `return (` 2 spaces as per config and then everything inside after has this same indent until `)`. Everything else is fine. I've tried many, few and no plugins and I keep hitting this wall. Plugins I have currently are: `Babel, DocBlockr, Emmet, EsLint, HTmL-CSS-JS Prettify, Less, Oceanic Next Color, Package control, PyV8, Sass, SublimeLinter, SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint, Theme - Spacegray`. Anyone else run into this?

I'm on Mac and its set to 2 indent

Comment: Consider using [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) for code formatting. It understands jsx and es6+.

Comment: Finally! Thanks FakeRainBrigand